# Java: Effect of @NonNull function returning null

Tags: java, android, null-safety

I have an old Java function in an Android project that is annotated with `@NonNull`. A few years after the function was written another developer added a branch that returns `null` and forgot to remove the annotation. This was discovered a few months later - I'm surprised the compiler didn't stop that from happening.

What potential issues could this or a similar situation cause, if any? Could this undermine null-safety when interoperating with Kotlin?

Answer (score -1):

It should cause a compile error.  But if a null is passed into a not nullable kotlin value, it would eventually lead to a crash when someone tried to dereference it.

Comment: Oddly enough it did not cause a compile error